# Dotnet CAP "has not been started" when running integration tests

Tags: c#, .net-7.0

I updated the version of Dotnet CAP lib in my project to the latest version (7.2.2), and after that I was trying to run my integration tests and then got an error saying **System.InvalidOperationException: 'CAP has not been started!'**. When I start my project and execute a request to publish a message with CAP there's no problem, I don't know what is the problem when running integration tests,in my tests I'm using a SharedContextAppFixture that injects my startup.

Tried to use other version of the Dotnet CAP lib, but the error persists,and I tried to inject the CAP lib in my integration tests.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.  Adding the below code can solve it:

```
var sp = host.Services;
var cts = new System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource();
sp.GetService<IBootstrapper>().BootstrapAsync(cts.Token);
var capPublisher = sp.GetRequiredService<ICapPublisher>();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the problem, 
[including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) 
really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are 
answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might 
not know the reasons for your code suggestion.